# Как реализовать такой блок в HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

У меня такой вопрос, как можно реализовать подобный блок и сами блоки (items)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `display: grid` и `grid-template-areas: 'icon p' 'icon span'` соответственно. А дальше приправить `grid-gap: 20px` и привязать `area` к элементам.

Comment: А если я использую флексы?

Comment: Какой такой.......?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение с помощью `display: grid;`

Добавил цвета для каждого блока.

```css
.blocks {
 display: grid;
 grid-gap: 30px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

.blocks .block {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-areas: 'img p' 'img span';
 align-items: center;
 grid-gap: 10px;
 width: 400px;
}

.block .icon {
 grid-area: img;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 padding: 10px;
}

.block .icon img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: contain;
}

.block.red .icon { background-color: rgba(245, 87, 103, 0.4); }
.block.blue .icon { background-color: rgba(37, 99, 255, 0.4); }
.block.green .icon { background-color: rgba(64, 151, 95, 0.4); }

.block p {
 grid-area: p;
 margin: 0;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.block.red p { color: #f55767; }
.block.blue p { color: #2563ff; }
.block.green p { color: #40975f; }

.block span {
 grid-area: span;
 font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
 <div class="block red">
  <div class="icon">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2687/2687779.svg" alt="">
  </div>
  <p>Fast Perfomance</p>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, deserunt sed amet obcaecati, eaque enim doloribus.</span>
 </div>
 <div class="block blue">
  <div class="icon">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2033/2033705.svg" alt="">
  </div>
  <p>Prototyping</p>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, deserunt sed amet obcaecati, eaque enim doloribus.</span>
 </div>
 <div class="block green">
  <div class="icon">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2752/2752514.svg" alt="">
  </div>
  <p>Vector Editing</p>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, deserunt sed amet obcaecati, eaque enim doloribus.</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое...

Comment: @Ibrahim, примите ответ, если он вас устроил, человек потратил на это время

Answer (score 1):

С помощью `display: flex;`

Добавил цвета как в вопросе для каждого блока.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 line-height: 1;
}

.block {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 width: 400px;
}

.block .icon {
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 flex-shrink: 0;
 padding: 10px;
}

.block-red .icon { background-color: #f55767; }
.block-blue .icon { background-color: #2563ff; }
.block-green .icon { background-color: #40975f; }

.block .icon img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: contain;
}

.block .description {
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.block .description p {
 font-size: 16px;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
 font-weight: 600;
}

.block-red p { color: #f55767; }
.block-blue p { color: #2563ff; }
.block-green p { color: #40975f; }

.block .description span {
 font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="blocks">
  <div class="block block-red">
   <div class="icon">
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2687/2687779.svg" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="description">
    <p>Fast Perfomance</p>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea quasi, unde, autem consequatur similique voluptas deserunt provident?</span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block block-blue">
   <div class="icon">
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2033/2033705.svg" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="description">
    <p>Prototyping</p>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea quasi, unde, autem consequatur similique voluptas deserunt provident?</span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block block-green">
   <div class="icon">
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2752/2752514.svg" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="description">
    <p>Vector Editing</p>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea quasi, unde, autem consequatur similique voluptas deserunt provident?</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Смотри: ( в голове представляй )
У тебя будет три блока: это каждый пункт ( fast perfomance, prototyping и vector editing )
Каждый этот блок разбей на 2 блока: в левых блоках у тебя иконки, а в правых текст ( в правых блоках еще h1 и p теги будут ), это с помощью флекса будет сделано все. Если не понятно, я могу скинуть код, как это сделать можно

Comment: На мой взгляд, это был очень понятный ответ. Но дело в том, что в каждом блоке есть цвет (фон для иконок и у каждого h1 свой цвет)... И проблема в том, что я туплю и не могу понять, как это сделать... Чтобы было правильно  и понятно

Comment: выкладывайте код сразу, а там уже поясняйте, так ответ будет нагляднее и лучше